# How to set focus to android alert dialog negative button?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have written code to setFocus to ALert Dialog negative button by using requestFocus(). But the button color will not change.I can able to set background image to that button manually.But i need that one directly from native.How to give focus to second button in 
ALlert Dialog?

Iam sending the code snippet for understanding

```
alertbox.show();
alertbox.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).requestFocus();
```

Even I tried with

```
alertbox.show();
alertbox.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).requestFocus(View.FOCUS_FORWARD)
```

Please any one can responde on this query?

Regards,
Android Developer

Comment: Are you running the requestFocus() function after the dialog is shown? To my understanding it won't have any effect if you try to focus a button before the dialog is visible.

Comment: after showing alert dialog only i have written above line.

Answer (score 21):

Just setOnShowListener() to AlertDialog, and set focus on the negative button.

```
    alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener(){

        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {

            Button negative = alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
            negative.setFocusable(true);
            negative.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            negative.requestFocus();
        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: can't find on MaterialAlertDialogBuilder