# Focus on button in dialog fragment

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am creating custom `DialogFragment` window with `AlertDialog.Builder` on Android. There is two cases regarding this window:

1. With neutral button only
2. With neutral and positive buttons.

In first case neutral button takes focus automatically (and this is what I need). And in second case - there is no focus on any button. But I need also focus on neutral button. How this can be solved?

```
public static class OrderDialog extends DialogFragment {
 public static OrderDialog newInstance(
                int view, String orderId, String data, Boolean status) {
            OrderDialog orderInfo = new OrderDialog();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putBoolean("status", status);
            args.putInt("view", view);
            args.putString("orderid", orderId);
            args.putString("data", data);
            orderInfo.setArguments(args);
            return orderInfo;
        }

      @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            int view = getArguments().getInt("view");
            String jsonResult = getArguments().getString("data");
            Boolean status = getArguments().getBoolean("status");
            String orderId = getArguments().getString("orderid");
            Boolean timeStampState = true;

            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            OrderObject orderObject;
            ApiResponse apiResponse;

            setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);

            final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(view, null);

          builder.setView(dialogView)
                    .setNeutralButton(R.string.barcode_rescan,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    ((ScannerActivity) getActivity())
                                            .retryScan();
                                }
                            });
            if (status)
                    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.order_sucess_button,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    ((ScannerActivity) getActivity())
                                            .checkInOrder(getOrderIdPost());
                                }
                            });

            return builder.create();
        }
```

And here is how this dialog is created:

```
DialogFragment getOrderResult;

if (result.first) {
    getOrderResult = OrderDialog.newInstance(
            R.layout.get_order_result_sucess,
            orderId,
            result.second,
            result.first
    );

} else {
    getOrderResult = OrderDialog.newInstance(
            R.layout.get_order_result_failure,
            orderId,
            result.second,
            result.first
    );

}

getOrderResult.show(getFragmentManager(), "order_result_dialog");
```

Comment: please post some code to be more clear

Comment: try this .http://stackoverflow.com/a/16164590/3912847

Comment: It is not my case,  because i'm using builder and have no possibility to add onShow listener