# AlertDialog negative button by default highlighted

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am using alert dialog with two buttons.Issue here is whenever my alert dialog gets displayed its negative button is shown highlighted.And this is happening in this dialog only rest other are working fine.Please suggest some solution.

Here is the code:

---

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

            alert.setTitle("Stop On The Go!");
            alert.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.tx_confirm_msg_journey));
            alert.setPositiveButton("Stop",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            stopTask();
                        }
                    });
            alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            navigateToHomePage();
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            alert.show();
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Atleast change: `Click to 'Stop' to start...` into `Click 'Stop' to start...` in your dialog message.

Comment: @ Strider thanx that will do, suggest some solution

Comment: @Swapnil did you try my answer??

Comment: You want focus on other button?

Comment: @sanky jain no i dont want focus on any of them.I just wan simple alert dialog.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16164590/2826147

Comment: @AmitVaghela Please read the comments before posting. He said he doesn't want any default highlight/focus.

Comment: I suppose the following would work -->           alert.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).clearFocus(); but what I'm more curious about is.. are you saying when this dialog first appears on the screen the negative button is pre-highlighted?

Comment: @Ryan yes dude. Even i was shocked,

Comment: yes thats odd, I've never seen this.  Which device and OS version are you running?  Do you have a custom dialog theme?

Comment: No normal doalog.And OS - 5.0.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use focus on positive

add this line in your positive button

```
 alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener(){

        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {

            Button positive= alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            positive.setFocusable(true);
            positive.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            positive.requestFocus();
        }
    });
```

Comment: change dailog like this..and let me know is it work :)

Comment: @Swapnil glad to help Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 7):

Show below code just change one line. `alert.show().getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).requestFocus();`

```
 AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());

    alert.setTitle("Stop On The Go!");
    alert.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.tx_confirm_msg_journey));
    alert.setPositiveButton("Stop",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    stopTask();
                }
            });
    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    navigateToHomePage();
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    alert.show().getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).requestFocus();
```

Comment: Not woking .requestFocus()

Comment: try `alert.show().getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).clearFocus()` if complite then edit answer

Comment: @Swapnil which theme used for application

Answer (score 3):

For Kotlin(in Android)

```
       AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Title")
            .setMessage("Do you want to cancel the Transaction?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton(
                "Yes"
            ) { dialog: DialogInterface, which: Int ->
                dialog.dismiss()
                // for sending data to previous activity use
                // setResult(response code, data)
                finish()
            }
            .setNegativeButton(
                "No"
            ) { dialog: DialogInterface, which: Int -> dialog.dismiss() }
            .show()
            .getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE)
            .requestFocus()
```

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer does not solve the problem. It just move focus to other button. Whereas OP

> "...dont want focus on any of them."

The real solution is:

```
alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener(){

    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {//To remove focus from button
        View rootView = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        rootView.setFocusable(true);
        rootView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        rootView.requestFocus();
    }
});
```

**UPDATE 13/07/18:** Is not acceptable for API 26.

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());// set title
alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("TITLE");
    // set dialog message
    alertDialogBuilder
    .setMessage("MESSAGE")
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton("YES",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
    //your positive message
    }
    });
    alertDialogBuilder     //   .setMessage("title")
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setNegativeButton("NO",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id){
    // if this button is clicked, close
    // current activity
    dialog.cancel();

    }
    });

    // create alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog=alertDialogBuilder.create();

    // show it
    alertDialog.show();
    }
```