# App looses focus after a dialogAlert is shown

Tags: android, xamarin, dialog, focus, alert

I am working on a dialog, and once I call it, there is no focus on it.
I am working on a xamarin app.

```
Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alertDialog.SetTitle("Special Notification Access");
alertDialog.SetMessage(
                    "You have no special app access permission for the Notifications!\n" +
                    "Please go to Settings -> Apps -> Special app access -> Notification access " +
                    "and give permission to this app."
);

alertDialog.SetPositiveButton("OK", (senderAlert, args) => {
    Android.Util.Log.Debug(TAG, "Pressed OK");
});

alertDialog.SetNegativeButton("No", (senderAlert, args) => {
    Android.Util.Log.Debug(TAG, "Pressed No");
});

Dialog diag = alertDialog.Create();
                
diag.Show();
```

Once I press a button on my remote (I am working on an Android TV, SDK 28) the dialog seems to get focus, but the log shows that the app has lost focus, see here:

```
09-10 13:37:24.974 12053 12053 W ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]: Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER, scanCode=353, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=13590499, downTime=13590499, deviceId=6, source=0x301 }
```

After that, the remote stops working, nothing is done by pressing the buttons. Also, once I open the settings (via ADB comand) and go back to the app, the dialog is in focus, and everything works fine.

I found various solutions on the net, including this:

[How to set focus to android alert dialog negative button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226587/how-to-set-focus-to-android-alert-dialog-negative-button)

Which uses the following code:

```
diag.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).requestFocus();
```

This method does not exit anymore.

Also, I found this:

```
alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener(){

        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {

            Button positive= alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            positive.setFocusable(true);
            positive.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            positive.requestFocus();
        }
});
```

But again, the setOnShowListener does not exist anymore.

What should I do?

Please let me know, if you need any more info.

Thank you for your time.

Edit1: Added picture

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with `SetOnShowListener` does not exist anymore? It hasn't been deprecated on either Dialog nor AlertDialog. Not sure where you got that information from... https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog#setOnShowListener(android.content.DialogInterface.OnShowListener)

Comment: @Cheesebaron I mean that the DialogInterface. has no OnShowListener...also, dialog does not have a function getButton, so even with the listener, I cannot acces the positive or negative button of the dialog, and cannot set focus to them, can u help me there?

Comment: Why not use a DialogFragment instead then?

Comment: It seems that the dialog fragment is working! :) thank you for the suggestion